# handling submit event - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that I'm trying to retool using jQuery to learn the library better and I am running into what seems to be a very elementary problem.

html:

```
<form id="theForm">
What would you like to do?<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="doThis" /><br /><br />
</form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#theForm").submit(function(){
    var doThis = $("#doThis").value.toLowerCase();      
    alert(doThis);
});
});
```

Can anybody offer some advice as to why this very simple interaction does not seem to work as it should?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) to get the value in jQuery

```
$("#doThis").val().toLowerCase();
```

The DOM object is not readily accessible off of `$()`, it is stored in `[0]` by jQuery, so if you wanted to access the value the traditional way, you would do:

```
$("#doThis")[0].value.toLowerCase();
```

Additionally, I don't think the form would submit right away in your case because of the `alert()`, but you should `return false;` to stop the submit if you don't intend on it submitting.

Comment: Thank you, Paolo. I did not know how to access the value within jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#theForm").submit(function(){
        var doThis = $("#doThis").value.toLowerCase();          
        alert(doThis);
return false
});
```

?